# Is there a T-SQL function to return the name of the 'sa' account?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sa

(I know the question sounds ridiculous, but bear with me ...)

Our DBA changes the 'sa' account name to something else for their own security purposes.  There are business needs to use the account name in script (e.g. sp_add_job), but this will break in this situation.  I'd like to be able to submit a script that doesn't need to be edited to use the new 'sa' username before running.

Is there a function/property similar to @@SERVERNAME that will return the name of this account?

Comment: They change the SA account name, but not the password?

Comment: @Mike Mooney: no, I assume they change the password as well.

Comment: So are you looking for something to return the SA username AND the SA password?  Then almost certainly not.  It would be a huge security hole  if you were able to run a script to retrieve the SA password.

Comment: @Mike Mooney: No, just the account name.

Comment: Just create an other user with the required privileges and use that. sa is deity, shouldn't be using it for day to day stuff.

Comment: @MikeMooney ROFL!  I'm just picturing a SELECT for the SA password returning a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME()
```

Comment: No, will this always be '1' for sa? i.e., "SELECT SUSER_NAME(1)"? because indeed that works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

There's no function to return the new SA name but since SA is UID = 0x01, it can be retrieved from the logins tables. This will work on SQL 2000 and up.

```
select name from master..syslogins where sid = 1
```